# regularity for fractional laplace equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Hey, I want to know what is the best interior regularity of the following equaiton:

$(-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}u=f$  in $B_{1}$ (ball with radius 1, centered at 0)
$f\in L^{\infty}(B_1)$

thanks

Comment: What is the regularity of $f$ in $B_1\setminus B_{1/2}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Luis Silvestre's work (e.g., Hölder estimates for solutions of integro differential equations like the fractional laplace, Indiana Univ. Math. J. 
55 (2006), 1155-1174) and classical potential theory estimates, taken together, give you $C^\alpha$ Hölder type regularity. Assuming, that is, that s is not too large.